# Get the array values of var inside a function in another

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, visual-studio, interop

I have a problem of understanding, about the function calls.
My first function in my 'excel' class is to find the cell with the name '* ID *'.

```
public IEnumerable<string> FindID()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 == "*ID*")
            {
                string ID = ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
                yield return ID;
                yield break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 == "*MAIN INFO END*")
                {
                    i = 1;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

My second function loops on the columns placed in the strings, like "name" or "searchable" to find all the values in the column and concat all value in a unique string for each row.

```
public IEnumerable<string> AttributeToForm(int i, int j)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
            {
                FindID();
                string label = ID;
                string name = ws.Cells[i, j + 1].Value2;
                string searchable = ws.Cells[i, j + 3].Value2;
                string FormField = "<FormField :span=\"6\" data-bwid =\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\" label=\"" + label + "\" ";
                if (searchable != null) {

                    FormField += string.Join("", "searchable");
                }
                if(FormField != null)
                {
                    FormField += string.Join("", "/>" + "\n");
                }
                else
                {

                }
                yield return label;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

**BUT**... What I really want would be to use in my 'AttributeToForm' function the string 'ID' contained in my 'FindID' function.. To get there I tried to run the **"FindID"** function and retrieve the **ID in a string**. However the result remains that of my string of class **"ID"**, so **"nothing"**.

```
class Excel
{
    private  int i = 1;
    private  int j = 1;
    private string ID = "nothing";...
```

Comment: Do you want only one id to be returned from FindID function?

Comment: no i want to return all the column but start from the cells who contains "*ID*"

Comment: I don't get what you want to achvieve here. Your `FindID` method will always only return the string `*ID*` if it is present or else will run forever. And in `AttributeToForm` you never use the value returned from `FindID`

Comment: so I would like to know how I can get the result of my string name but using the FindID function in my AttributeToForm Function

Comment: I think what I really want would be to use in my 'AttributeToForm' function the string 'ID' contained in my 'FindID' function. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, you would like to make a method to get all the columns.

You can try the following code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = FindColumn("id");
            var name = FindColumn("name");
            var searchable = FindColumn("search");

        }

        public IEnumerable<string> FindColumn(string name)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            try
            {

                int row = worksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
                int column = worksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Column;
                int a = 1;
                int b = 1;
                int c = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < row + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < column + 1; j++)
                    {
                        string value = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Text;
                        if (value == name)
                        {
                            a = i;
                            b = j;
                        }
                        string vlaue2 = worksheet.Cells[i, b].Text;
                        if (vlaue2 == "*MAIN INFO END")
                        {
                            c = i;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                for (int j = a + 1; j < c; j++)
                {
                    list.Add(worksheet.Cells[j, b].Text);
                }

                return list.AsEnumerable();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\1.xlsx");
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        }
    }
```

My Excel file :(almost same with you)

[image]

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thank for this answer. :)  it helps me, but what i want is to be able to find each column using a "Find" function like my "FindID" function. Suddenly I will also have a function "FindName" and "Find Search", in order to avoid fixed values, if ever there is a column is moved.

Comment: i think i wanted something like that `string label = FindLabel();`
                `string name = FindName();`
                `string searchable = FindSearchable();`

Comment: @Calvin, I have modified my code and you can check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Jack J Jun - MSFT

My excel look like this

[image]